# Powershell - Sendkeys - Send the same key multiple times

Tags: powershell

How do you send the same key multiple times in Powershell?

I know that in Excel VBA you can use `...::SendWait("{TAB 10}")`.  However, this does not seem to work in Powershell.  I have confirmed this by testing the same function with `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}")` entered 10 times.

Comment: Why are you sending keys at all? That is quite prone to failure.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce your issue. [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}");
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}");
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}")  works for me, as does 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}"*3)

Comment: WayneA, yes, but you gave me the right answer.  I did not have the `*3`.  I just had `("{TAB 10}")`.  However, with what you said, it should be `("{TAB}"*10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting comment into answer:

What you are looking for is

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")
```

which a cool powershell trick allows you to write as

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}"*10)
```